# Jenkinsfile when condition that contains branch pattern does not apply

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I want by pipeline to run on any branch that matches the pattern `alerta/` (and anything beyond the slash (`/`).

So I have tried the following 2 approaches in terms of `Jenkinsfile`

```
          expression {
              env.BRANCH_NAME ==~ 'alerta\/.*'
          }
```

```
          expression {
              env.BRANCH_NAME == '*/alerta/*'
          }
```

both of them have the corresponding stages being skipped.

How should I format my `when` conditional to meet my purpose?

Answer (score 1):

You forgot to return the state in the expression

> **expression**
>
> Execute the stage when the specified Groovy expression evaluates to
> true, for example: `when { expression { return params.DEBUG_BUILD } }`
> Note that when returning strings from your expressions they must be
> converted to booleans or return null to evaluate to false. Simply
> returning "0" or "false" will still evaluate to "true".

```
pipeline {
    agent any
    stages {
        stage('alerta-branch'){
            when{
                expression {
                    return env.BRANCH_NAME ==~ /alerta\/.*/
                }
            }
            steps {
                echo 'run this stage - ony if the branch contains alerta in branch name'
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This should work for you